# PHPWORD Alinear texto al centro

Tags: php, phpword

Estoy trabajando con PHPWORD hace pocos días y estoy intentando alinear un texto al centro pero no logro hacerlo, también no puedo centrar un texto verticalmente en una celda de mi tabla, agradecería su ayuda.
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$seccion->addText(htmlspecialchars('CERTIFICADO DE ACEPTACIÓN'),array('name' => 'Century 
Gothic', 'size' => '12', 'bold' => TRUE, 'align'=>'center'));

 $table->addRow();
 $cell = $table->addCell(3600);
 $cell->addText(htmlspecialchars('COORDINADOR'), array('name' => 'Century Gothic', 'size' => 
 '11', 'bold' => TRUE, 'valign'=>'center'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el estilo `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Alignment::ALIGN_CENTER` de esta forma:

```
$section->addText('Hola Stackoverflow!', [], [ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Alignment::ALIGN_CENTER ]);
```

En tu código sería:

```
$seccion->addText(htmlspecialchars('CERTIFICADO DE ACEPTACIÓN'),array('name' => 'Century 
Gothic', 'size' => '12', 'bold' => TRUE, 'align'=>'center'), [ 'align' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Alignment::ALIGN_CENTER ]);
```

Comment: No me reconoce el estilo Alignment, reviese la carpeta de PHPWORD y ese estilo no existe

Comment: Que versión de  PHPWord usas? @JeisonDavilaLlanten

Comment: Tengo la ultima version 18.2